# Centos 7 - Script not runing from init d - manually with & it starts in background

Tags: bash, service, centos7, init.d, rc

I have created script in init.d

```
/etc/init.d/startSanic

#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/horses
./startSanic.sh &
```

`startSanic` is with permissions `777`
startSanic.sh is with permissions `755`

I intentionally created two scripts because only if I start script manually with `&` it will start and it will not be killed if I close the session.

I created link in rc5.d (my runlevel is 5 but I created also for rc2,3,4)

```
S97startSanic -> ../init.d/startSanic
```

My service is always being run on port 9000.
If I check after the reboot of the server it is not being run with this script in init.d.
What can be the issue?

My /opt/horses/startSanic.sh script uses ONLY two  lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

gunicorn horses.server:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker --reload
```

Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Scripts in `init.d` are not simple bash scripts. They should implement the [interface](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/init.d).

Comment: Hi @RemisaYousefvand can you please assist me to write this script in init.d  I really have big problems to write it and I updated my question - you can see that it is only just one line which should be triggered by the script 
"gunicorn horses.server:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker --reload"

Comment: Using `systemd` is prefered. [Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux) is a tutorial on how to run your bash script as service at startup. Let me know if you have any questions on that.

Comment: Hi @RemisaYousefvand is this for Centos 7 applicable example? I do not see it is

Comment: Yes. Modern Linux distros, including CentOS 7 support `systemd`.

Comment: Hi @RemisaYousefvand I created new question because it is not working even with your suggested way. Please take a look I really think I did it properly. Please check and assist if you have little time. Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479450/centos-7-service-from-etc-systemd-system-san-service-not-running-with-systemct