# Centos 7 - service from /etc/systemd/system/san.service not running with systemctl start san.service

Tags: service, centos, systemd, init.d, systemctl

I followed instructions from this link: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-make-custom-script-to-run-automatically-during-boot/

But I have issue because my service is not being run.

I created one script startSanic2.sh which invokes startSanic.sh script (I need this because when I start it manually with & only in this case session is not expired)

This is my script startSanic2.sh

```
# cat /opt/horses/startSanic2.sh 
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/horses
./startSanic.sh &
```

This is my script startSanic.sh

```
# cat /opt/horses/startSanic.sh 
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn horses.server:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker --reload
```

After this is run (./startSanic2.sh) it is being run successfully on port 9000.

startSanic.sh and startSanic2.sh have permissions 755

I then created new san.service

```
[root@testnn2 system]# cat /etc/systemd/system/san.service
[Unit]
Description=Description for sample script goes here
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I run this command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And I run this command

```
# systemctl enable san.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/san.service to /etc/systemd/system/san.service
```

When I run it - nothing happens :(

```
systemctl start san.service
```

I checked and in `/etc/systemd/system`
my san.service looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  193 Apr  2 18:07 san.service
```

Please assist me on this issue why nothing is being run.

**Update:** environment variables

Content of `/etc/systemd/system/san.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description for sample script goes here
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0
Environment="var1=value1"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `startSanic2.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/horses/startSanic.sh
```

Make sure it is executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
```

Also make sure `startSanic.sh` is executable:

```
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/horses/startSanic.sh
```

Reload daemon and enable it:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl enable san.service
$ sudo systemctl start san.service
```

Reboot machine.

Update:

Set environment variables in `san.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Description for sample script goes here
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0
Environment="REDIS_HOST=192.168.150.220"
Environment="REDIS_PORT=6379"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: it's not woriking. Still nothing is running. If I run it manually like this " ./startSanic2.sh & " then it is working while if I run it manully like this "./startSanic2.sh " then it is running only while the session is active. But with service it is not working. Please help :(

Comment: netstat -tulpn|grep 9000   - with this I am checking if something is being run on the port which I configured or not. Because as I stated if I run it manually then I can see that something is being run on this port. Then I kill it and start as service but nothing happens:( thanks for helping me:(

Comment: Also with ./startSanic2.sh & I am getting the pid number on which I can see that is being run on port 9000

Comment: What is the output of this command: `sudo journalctl -u san.service`

Comment: It seems that Service has issue with my environment variables because I have two environment variables in ~/.bashrc  export REDIS_HOST=192.168.150.220
export REDIS_PORT=6379  variables are set for root : Please take a look at this full output it reports that there is some error that it cannot read my variable REDIS_PORT = int(os.getenv('REDIS_PORT'))
 TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'                                                         this is the URL for output
 we.tl/t-4sQrVaEGvi

Comment: So it seems that is is struggling to read environment variable which is defined in .bashrc for root user. But I think this is really typical use case. Do you please have an idea how to overcome this?

Comment: add `Environment="var1=val1"` under `[Service]` in `san.service` file

Comment: Thanks Remisa it seems it is working. I will reboot the server to check if it is being run succesfully!!! I marked your response as answer!  If I may just one more question sorry - I put for After =network.target, but actually I need to run my service after service on port 6379 is run that is redis_6379  I have that in init.d and it is in rc5.d but for this redis there is nothing in /usr/lib/systemd/system . So how I can be sure that san.service is being run after redis_6379 . Please if you can answer me on this also. I marked answer and MANY MANY THANKS

Comment: I guess adding `After=rc-local.service` in `[Unit]` section does the job.

Comment: Aha and then it will run everthing which it has in /etc/init.d (that is redis_6379) and everything which it has in rc5.d (that is  S10network -> ../init.d/network
 S50redis_6379 -> ../init.d/redis_6379)  When you said "I guess adding ...." I think you thought "replacing instead of After=network.target" correct? Thanks

Comment: I said guess since never had a `systemd` service to be run after an `init.d` one. They are not compatible. I guess there is no exact solution for run after service `X` so they support `After=rc-local.service` to run after all `init.d` services. Another solution is checking port inside your script in a loop with `sleep` which obviously is not a clean solution. Best solution is running the other service with `systemd`.

Comment: Thank you once again. I think that this will do the trick After=rc-local.service

Comment: can you please maybe assist me and with this other issue? Thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493637/limit-logs-for-journalctl-services-in-systemd-centos-7