# Limit logs for "journalctl services" in systemd - Centos 7

Tags: logging, service, centos7, systemd, systemd-journald

I have a service in `**/etc/systemd/sysem/horses.service**`

```
[Unit]
Description=Description for sample script goes here
After=rc-local.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0
Environment="REDIS_HOST=192.168.150.220"
Environment="REDIS_PORT=6379"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It runs the shell script with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
gunicorn horses.server:app --bind 0.0.0.0:9000 --worker-class sanic.worker.GunicornWorker --reload
```

I succesfully run it and I can see the logs of the service are being written and can be read from:

```
journalctl -u horses.service
```

if I run that command - I can see all events which that horses.service logs.

I do not have any experience with logs for systemd services.
My very big concern is that because this service will be running all the time - is it possible for example to set to keep the information (logs) in journalctl -u horses.service only for example for last 10 days, or to define some round logging or whatever method is suggested in order to be sure that my logs will not be full because I do want to end with my whole disk (partition) full.
Please suggest me how I can limit the logs.

Thank you in advance!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see by running `journalctl -u` is the output of your app to console (or errors) which `systemd` take care of them for you.

The global configurations can be find at `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and default values will serve your concern, so you are Ok with default values.

Btw, here are configurations you can use to alter the logging behavior:

- `SystemKeepFree`: How much disk space leave for other applications
  (default = 15%).
- `SystemMaxuse`: Maximum disk space usage (default =    10%).

By default `systemd` keep logs as long as it can (restricted by above rules) however if you need a rotation based configuration you can use `MaxRetentionSec`.

And again, you don't need to worry about disk usage by `systemd`, just use default configurations.

Comment: thank you for response. My configuration is following : #SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
  does it mean it has default values 15% and 10%? Also is it possible that I create some new log where all requests (output of the service) which are currently logged in journald.conf to be seen also in some of my new log file.? For example in my horses.service will it be possible to add something like this (or what will be the right syntax)  [Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh >> "/var/log/horses/horses"+`date +"%s"` 2>&1 . Probably I missed something but really not sure

Comment: Yes even with commented configurations `systemd` still uses default values. For the second part of your question `StandardOutput=file:/var/log/horses/horses` also you can do the same for `StandardError`. `systemd` adds date/time information to logs so you don't need to do that manually. You can filer logs by date via `--since` and `--until` switches. Example: `journalctl --since "2019-04-01 18:22:34" --until "2019-04-04 16:22:19"`

Comment: Hi Remisa - and in this case it will create me a new file only when I restart the service correct? Which means if for example my service is active without restart for three month it will meen that I will have one single three months log which can be huge size? Correct? Or I can limit for this StandardOutput=file: the size and number of logs??? Please if you can provide me answer on this also. Thanks. I marked your response.

Comment: @Dejan: I'm not sure but it is highly possible that rotation rules will be applied to your file too (since it does with default log storage). You can limit file sizes by setting `SystemMaxFileSize`. Set it to a small amount and check if rotation happens to your custom file.

Comment: Hi Remisa OK because some of the configuration are being done in service file horses please correct me if I am wrong: `[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/horses/startSanic2.sh
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/horses/horsesout
StandardError=file:/var/log/horses/horseserr`  while if I want to change default file size for those logs i will change it in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. Correct? Of course these log files will not be deleted automatically correct? For them rules SystemMaxuse and SystemKeepFree are not applied? Thanks, all the best